# Database, Keyvalue pairs, addition of new columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

This is a question on the best approach to solve a certain database problem.

We have a database with a table with key value pairs as below.

```
        Key   Value
         x      1
         y      45
         z      60
```

Now in our new iteration we would have many combinations of the key value pairs so we want to store that. A simple solution would be

```
     Id       key       value
      0         x          1
      0         y          45
      0         z          60
      1         x          10
      1         y          3
      1         z          9
```

etc.

Now I was also thinking along the lines of having x,y,z as columns in the second table so we simply just store the values of these under the columns without the Id repeating. However the problem would be when you want to add a new key into the database. (This isn't a daily occurrence, rarely it is added).

What is the best approach to solve this problem? Should we use the method shown above in demonstration or the one I suggested or is there another solution that is better than the two?

Comment: Do you want to keep both the tables in the new iteration or you want to migrate to new table?

Comment: I will keep the old table and create a new table in the new iteration

Comment: In second approach ,in future If you need to add a new key rather than(x,y,z).It will not be simple modification

Comment: I will go with new table like ( ID auto increment, IterationId, Key from the first table). I am not sure what will suits better.